# Spring Boot Unit test pre-initialization before @Configuration

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a SpringBootTest where I need to initialize some stuff before the Spring @Configuration classes are processed. My data sources are loaded from JNDI, so I need to initialize the JNDI context before it processes the @Configuration class that contains my data source configuration. How can I accomplish this? I tried by using the setUp method in my unit test, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your code? Are you using spring-boot to load your jndi context? Also what version of spring-boot 1.4 comes with some nice testing features.

Comment: JNDI in a unit test doesn't  sound right. How about using a local database for your tests? As Nicholas said, Spring Boot 1.4 can even override the datasource for you if you want. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing something similar to what's posted here: http://en.newinstance.it/2009/03/27/mocking-jndi/

Yeah, it's a little unorthodox to "mock" JNDI, but I wanted a true unit test where if JNDI were available and the data sources were under JNDI, my code was able to pull the data sources out and use them appropriately.